# How can I view PDF's in nw.js?

Tags: node-webkit, nw.js

Folks - I'm at a loss, I've followed the instructions as per the manifest here: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Third-party-browser-plugins

- I've included `"plugin": true` in the "webkit" section.
- I've located PDF.plugin file from Chrome's Internet Plug-ins folder and added it to my nw.js app's `{root}/plugins` folder

I just can't view any pdf file. I keep receiving `'Couldn't load plug-in'`

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody please offer some advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PDF.js implementation such as [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/).